# ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: onloadCallback Angular 6 Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, recaptcha

I'm getting: ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: onloadCallback

I have my call to the Google API in index.html

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

In my component a few levels in the app/ directory, I have a validation page whereby the user uses reCaptcha to validate they're human.

**Here's a fragment of my .ts file**

```
public siteKeyCaptcha = 'Sgsfsdfs3212424233423424dddddddddd-' <!-- FAKE KEY-->;
public reCaptchaWidgetId = 'recaptcha1';


ngOnInit() {

    this.validationCommentSuccess = false;
    this.validationCommentDanger = false;
    this.onloadCallback = this.onloadCallback.bind(this);
    try {
        grecaptcha.render(this.reCaptchaWidgetId, {
       'sitekey': this.siteKeyCaptcha,
       'callback': 'onloadCallback'
       });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error on Try Catch: ', error);
    }
    this.btnValue = 'Welcome! Prove you\'re human first then click here.';

    this.sessionStorageService.set('appInsIDSectId', this.temporaryPath);
    this.getFingerPrint().then(data => console.log('DEVICE FINGER PRINT: ', data));

    // This is needed to get the reCaptcha working or it'll say it can't find it
    this.onloadCallback(grecaptcha.getResponse());
}
```

**Here's the fragment from the .html file**

```
    <form id="form-validation" novalidate method="post">
      <div class="login__brand"></div>
      <h1 class="h3 my-3 text-center">Welcome to Digital Harbor</h1>
      <h2 class="h2 my-2 text-center">Click the button below to enter Set Forms</h2>


      <div id="recaptcha1" class="g-recaptcha" 
           data-expired-callback="disableBtn"
           data-sitekey='Sgsfsdfs3212424233423424dddddddddd-' <!-- FAKE KEY-->
           data-callback="enableBtn"
           data-expired-callback="expiredCallback"></div>

      <button class="mt-3 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
              id="submitValidateBtn"
              type="submit"
              (click)="validation()"
              [innerHTML]='btnValue'></button>

    </form>
```

**The code in the .ts file**

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.submitbtn = document.getElementById('submitValidateBtn') as HTMLElement;
    // Start with a disabled Submit Button
    this.disableBtn();
      window.enableBtn = (data: any) => {
        console.log('Inside Global Callback Method Enable ', data);
        this.enableBtn();
      };
      window.disableBtn = (data: any) => {
        if (data === 'expiredmsg') {
          console.log('Inside Global Callback Method Disable ', data);
          this.submitbtn.innerText = 'Oops! Please reverify to continue.';
        }
        this.disableBtn();
      };
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {

  }

  public async getFingerPrint() {
    this.deviceFingerPrint = await this.httpService.getDeviceFingerprint();
    return this.deviceFingerPrint;
  }

  public onSubmit(event: any) {
    console.log('EVENT onSubmit: ', event);
    if (this.checkCaptcha && grecaptcha.getResponse(this.reCaptchaWidgetId) != "") {
      this.submitted = true;
      this.enableBtn();
    }
  }

  public verifyCallback(response: any) {
    console.log('ReCaptcha Response Verified: ', response);
    if (grecaptcha.getResponse(this.reCaptchaWidgetId).length !== 0) {
      this.checkCaptcha = false;
    } else {
      this.checkCaptcha = true;
    }
  }

  public onloadCallback(captchaResponse: string) {
    if (captchaResponse === "") {
      console.log('grecaptcha is NOT ready!');
    } else {
      console.log('grecaptcha is ready!');
      this.recaptcha.verifyUserResponse(captchaResponse);
      this.verifyCallback(captchaResponse);
    }
  }

  public expiredCallback() {
    this.submitbtn.innerText = 'EXPIRED! Click Captcha to prove you\'re human again!';
    this.submitbtn.classList.add('disableBtn');
    this.submitbtn.classList.remove('enableBtn');
    this.submitbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }

  public disableBtn(): void {
    this.submitbtn.classList.add('disableBtn');
    this.submitbtn.classList.remove('enableBtn');
    this.submitbtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    this.submitbtn.innerText = 'Click Captcha to prove you\'re human!';
  }

  public enableBtn(): void {
    this.onloadCallback(grecaptcha.getResponse(this.reCaptchaWidgetId));
    this.submitbtn.classList.add('enableBtn');
    this.submitbtn.classList.remove('disableBtn');
    this.submitbtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    this.submitbtn.innerText = 'Welcome! Prove you\'re human first then click here.';
  }
```

**My GOAL is:**

1. Verify captcha and ENABLE the button (submit)
2. Once Verified I don't want to get this error in the debug console.

ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: onloadCallback

and

ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: expiredCallback

Question:

Is that because the JS script call in index.html is too far up the food chain to find onloadCallback?

I tried moving it into the HTML file but the reCaptcha widget never renders

Thank you

Comment: How in the world could the library find your function? It is inside of a component instance.  If you use the `?onload=onLoadCallback` query param to specify the on load callback, `onLoadCallback` has to be the name of a global variable. Hint: global variables in a browser are properties of the `window` variable.

Comment: Aluan, thank you. I appreciate your candor and forthrightness but please tell me your solution. window.onLoadCallBack?  This is what's at the top under my imports:  declare const grecaptcha: ReCAPTCHA;
declare const window: any;

Comment: (Note: **module** here refers to JavaScript modules, and has nothing to do with Angular) You should remove both of those declarations. You're saying those variables exist inside your module. they won't actually exist because you use the declare keyword but what you want to do is manipulate the global variable window. Instead you are shadowing it with a module scoped declaration. Remove both of those `declare const` statements and assign a function to the global variable named window: `window.onLoadCallback = (args) => { //logic };`. However, this has to be done _before_ ReCAPTCHA is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I was following an example on Stackoverflow, but I think it's overkill.  So, my component is off the app folder, app/auth-module/email-validation/ and so that's where I'm at with the folder structure.  I'll try your suggestion, sir. Thanks

Comment: Aluan, could you please give me a full example of window.onloadCallback above and do I put in the component or in app.component.ts?  Thank you, sir

Comment: Looking over your code, you are explicitly specifying the callback when you invoke `grecaptcha.render`. This is preferrable to adding a global function. Just remove `?onload=onloadCallback` from the `src` of your script tag